# Error when using ColorFunction in Parametric3DPlot

Tags: plotting

I am running the following code

```
Posvec = {Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ], Sin[ϕ] Sin[θ], 
Cos[θ]};
L = ParametricPlot3D[
Posvec, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {θ, π/2, π} , 
ColorFunction -> 
Function[{x, y, z, ϕ, θ}, Hue[1/θ^2]]]
```

For some reason that I do not understand, I get a zero division error. About any help I would be very glad

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are falling victim to the following line from the [documentation of `ColorFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html#2806):

> With the usual default setting `ColorFunctionScaling->True`, all arguments supplied to *func* are scaled to lie in the range 0 to 1.

Consequently, all points with `θ=π/2` will be rescaled to `θ=0` (since π/2 is the smallest value for θ), causing the warning message (and the wrong colors). Specify `ColorFunctionScaling->False` to prevent this:

```
Posvec = {Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ], Sin[ϕ] Sin[θ], Cos[θ]};
ParametricPlot3D[Posvec, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {θ, π/2, π}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, ϕ, θ}, Hue[1/θ^2]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thankk! that helped a lot!